# How to manage incoming call notifications in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

So I'm making an app (its a pet project of mine and I'm also using the same project for an assignment in college) and its a productivity app of sorts and in that app I need to implement a mode (ultra focus mode). When that mode is turned on the user basically should not be disturbed by any kind of notifications from any app or even system notification. For now I've managed the notifications of other apps they don't show up when that mode is turned on and also I switch the ringer mode to silent so there is no notification sound. But I cannot figure out how to work with the call notification when the call comes the notification is popped up which is what I don't want to happen nothing else should be visible to the user except the app screen. How can I go about implementing that. Also I've handled the other notifications using the NotificationListenerService. Basically something like a game mode in gaming apps where the user gets no notifications of any type when the game mode is turned on. One method I thought of was to set the device to DND mode but my professor wants me to explore other options.